# Как отследить неудачное подключение к аккаунту Pyrogram?

Tags: python, pyrogram

Проблема заключается в том, что я подключаюсь к аккаунту используя прокси, но если прокси невалид, то pyrogram пытается переподключиться к аккаунту бесконечное количество раз, пока я не завершу скрипт, мне нужно как то отследить неудачное подключение и стопнуть клиент, но суть в том, что неудачное подключение это не ошибка и в except оно не уходит.